# Raspberry Pi as a internal Wifi access point but connecting to external Wifi

Tags: wifi

I have several IOT nodes that connect to Wifi, and a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W which will act as a server.

This system will be mobile and it's connection to the internet will be via publicly available Wifi connections (e.g. in cafes and hotels).

I'd like the server to act as a wifi access point, and the IOT nodes will connect to it. That way when I change location I don't need to reconfigure the SSID / password on each of the nodes. Also, I will be able to control the internal address space and I can assign static IPs to the server and nodes.

There's several explanations on how to set a Raspberry Pi up as an access point, but they all assume the Pi will connect to the internet with an ethernet cable.

Is what I'm trying to do impossible? Perhaps the Wifi chip on the Pi is just incapable of connecting to a Wifi access point while simultaneously accepting incoming Wifi connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My other answer for this provides a method of getting the Raspberry Pi working as a wifi access point, but it was totally unreliable. Regular disconnects and failed connection attempts.

In the end I've given up and ordered a hardware "mini router" - the GL.iNet GL-MT300N-V2... This can create an internal wifi network and route to an external wifi network. So far this is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: this has proved so unreliable I'd highly recommend not following these instructions! (see comment below)**

I've worked out the answer to this, and created a [set of instructions here](https://github.com/dave/iot/blob/main/access-point.md).

I'll post the instructions here too, but best to check my github link above in case I update them.

## Setup

I've been configuring an IOT network, which has a Raspberry Pi as a server, and several iot
nodes. They all communicate over wifi. During development, they all need internet access.

However, I change location quite frequently so reconfiguring them all with static IPs and new
wifi credentials every time I change wifi location was a real pain.

These instructions will configure a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W as a wifi access point so all the
iot nodes can connect to it to join the local network. That way they can all have a predictable
internal IP address range, and a stable set of wifi credentials.

Not only is the Raspberry Pi server an access point, it also connects to an external wifi network
using standard DHCP, and routes internet traffic between the internal iot network and the external
public network.

Additionally, these instructions are assuming you don't have a keyboard and screen attached to
the Pi. It's all configured in a headless SSH session. We will approximately follow
[these instructions](https://imti.co/iot-wifi/) to install docker and pull image (but we skip
the `disable wpa_supplicant` step until the end, because it will disable wifi and lock you out
of the Pi):

### Things you might need on your Mac (optional)

- Jq tool for displaying json on command line: `brew install jq`
- Nmap network scanner `brew install nmap`
- Make a shortcut to the airport tool so it's easier to use: `sudo ln -s /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport /usr/local/bin/airport`

### Instructions

1. We'll be using the [Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) tool to write the Pi OS to an SD card.
2. Remember to set hostname, ssh access and locale settings in the `Advanced options` panel before you flash.
3. Flash Raspberry Pi OS Lite 32-bit version. I've tested with the 2022-04-04 OS version.
4. *Mac* Try to ssh in with the hostname configured in the Imager settings: `ssh pi@XXX.local`
5. *Mac* If that fails, scan local network for the Pi (here XXX is the local range that your Mac is on): `sudo nmap -sn 192.168.XXX.0/24 | grep -B 2 Raspberry`, then ssh to Pi on local address: `ssh pi@192.168.XXX.XXX`
6. *Pi* Install Docker: `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com | sh`
7. *Pi* Update permissions: `sudo usermod -aG docker pi`
8. *Pi* Reboot: `sudo reboot`
9. SSH will disconnect, so reconnect once it's rebooted.
10. *Pi* Pull the Docker image: `docker pull cjimti/iotwifi`
11. *Pi* Create `wificfg.json` config file and edit credentials:

```
{
    "dnsmasq_cfg": {
      "address": "/#/192.168.27.1",
      "dhcp_range": "192.168.27.100,192.168.27.150,1h",
      "vendor_class": "set:device,IoT"
    },
    "host_apd_cfg": {
       "ip": "192.168.27.1",
       "ssid": "INTERNAL_SSID_IN_HERE",
       "wpa_passphrase":"INTERNAL_PASS_IN_HERE",
       "channel": "6"
    },
      "wpa_supplicant_cfg": {
        "cfg_file": "/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf"
    }
}
```

12. *Pi* Start Docker container: `docker run --restart=unless-stopped -d --privileged --net host -v $(pwd)/wificfg.json:/cfg/wificfg.json cjimti/iotwifi`
13. Pi will freeze and stop pinging for a few seconds here, but give it time and the SSH connection will start responding again.
14. Enable forwarding:
15. *Pi* `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
16. *Pi* `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE`
17. *Pi* `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o uap0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`
18. *Pi* `sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i uap0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT`
19. *Pi* Enable and configure `iptables` persistence: `sudo apt install iptables-persistent`
20. Now we can return to the `disable wpa_supplicant` step:
21. *Pi* `sudo systemctl mask wpa_supplicant.service`
22. *Pi* `sudo mv /sbin/wpa_supplicant /sbin/no_wpa_supplicant`
23. *Pi* `sudo pkill wpa_supplicant`
24. SSH to Pi will freeze because the Pi's wifi will be disconnected.
25. Reboot Pi
26. *Mac* Check you have the Pi's internal wifi network: `airport scan | grep SSID_IN_HERE`
27. *Mac* Connect to the internal wifi newtork (you won't have internet yet).
28. Once you're connected to this network you'll be able to ssh to the Pi on `192.168.27.1`, but we shouldn't need to do that right now.
29. Now you can use curl to configure the Pi's external wifi:
30. *Mac* Get Pi to return status: `curl -w "\n" http://192.168.27.1:8080/status | jq`
31. *Mac* Get Pi to scan wifi networks: `curl -w "\n" http://192.168.27.1:8080/scan | jq`
32. *Mac* Get Pi to connect to a network: `curl -w "\n" -d '{"ssid":"SSID_IN_HERE", "psk":"PASSWORD_IN_HERE"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://192.168.27.1:8080/connect | jq`
33. Internet should now be working on Mac

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what is wrong with this, but running the Pi as a wifi access point was totally unreliable. Regular disconnects and failed connection attempts. In the end I've given up and ordered a hardware "mini router" - the GL.iNet GL-MT300N-V2... This can create an internal wifi network and route to an external wifi network. So far this is working perfectly.